# What is the name of a word that doesn't mean what it says?

Tags: meaning

Like the group "Anonymous," they are not REALLY anonymous since they are all over media outlets. Is there a word for that?

Edit: Autoantonym almost sounds right but that seems to imply it has two meanings like left the airport vs going left. This one doesn't mean well known, it is the complete opposite of the actual word.

Comment: An *unrepresentative* name?

Comment: Autoantonym almost sounds right but that seems to imply it has two meanings like left the airport vs going left. This one doesn't mean well known, it is the complete opposite of the actual word.

Comment: How does being on a media outlet make you not anonymous? Are the media outlets naming them, or just reporting their statements?

Comment: If your group is called anonymous, you would think you would be anonymous and no one would know you. But if you become known, it doesn't seem to fit quite right. We know technically it means you don't know the names of the people involved of course. I was thinking there was a clever word for it. Like how it was suggested as autoantonym..

Comment: Could you be thinking of the word ***Ironic***?

Comment: @traveler84: Perhaps the word you're looking for is [**oxymoronic**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oxymoron). We usually use that of *combinations* of words whose meanings seem inherently contradictory *(freezer burn, jumbo shrimp, working vacation...)*, but I don't see why we shouldn't apply it to a single word like ***Anonymous*** when that specifically refers to a ***well-known*** group.

Comment: @Hank yeah, that seems by definition what I must be thinking. I thought there'd be a fancier word to sound smarter for a joke. "The ironically named group Anonymous..." Fill out an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Duplicate of *Word or phrase that can be used to say that a particular word doesn't describe* {itself accurately}. **'Misnomers'**....

Comment: @Mazura It's not a `Misnomer` if the name was intended to describe itself inaccurately. `Misnomer` implies that the naming was accidentally done incorrectly, as opposed to purposely done incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[***Ironic***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/ironic) seems to fit your situation

> #### Ironic
>
> - Using words to express the opposite of their literal meaning.

Irony is similar to sarcasm, but the goal of sarcasm is to mock, while irony is usually used to make subtler points.

Comment: You need to explain answer this further so that it fully answers the question. At the moment, it needs expanding.